# amazon swf Storage file or DB for Amazon Simple workflow

Tags: amazon-swf

Can any one please tell where will the workflows created using code will get saved.

What will be file format and what will be the extension for that file

Also can you please get me some examples if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are saved inside SWF Service. You can get workflow history through its visibility API.

Comment: Hi Maxim Thanks much for your answer. As far i searched the format in which the SWF history get saved is JSON. Please correct me If I am wrong

Comment: How is history is stored is proprietary AWS information. It can be retrieved as Jason using http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_GetWorkflowExecutionHistory.html call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Maxim